# apple ios security framework missing

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

Ok, i have my build working fine in xcode 4.3 , i upgraded to xcode4.5 and now security framework is missing. 
It's not even appearing in project settings > Build phases > Link binary with libraries.

What should i do?

Comment: You may have to reinstall some of the downloads after you upgrade XCode, like the command-line tools, maybe the Mac OS X Core Library...I hope this helps.